# Access different object within a ngFor

Tags: html, angular-material

I have a mat-grid-list which itterates through some auctions I have created to make the different mat-grid-tiles.
Inside my auction I have CarId and BidId.
Inside my ngFor="let auction of auctions" I want to access those Ids and use them to show CarType and bid amount from the Car and Bid objects.

In the following code I would like to switch out "0" in:

{{allCars[0].CarType}} 
{{bids[0].Amount}}

Switch it so I can access and use {{auctions.CarId}} and {{auctions.BidId}} to connect the correct car type and bid amount to the mat-grid-tile.
Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
      <mat-grid-list cols={{breakpoint}} rowHeight="150px" gutterSize="1" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let auction of auctions"
                       [colspan]="1"
                       [rowspan]="1"
                       [style.border]="'1px double black'"
                       [style.background]="lightblue">


          <div class="text-inside-grid">
            Bil type:
            {{allCars[0].CarType}}
            <br />
            Start dato:
            {{auction.StartDate.toLocaleTimeString()}}
            {{auction.StartDate.toLocaleDateString()}}
            <br />
        Slutt dato:
        {{auction.StartDate.toLocaleTimeString()}}
        {{auction.EndDate.toLocaleDateString()}}
        <br />
        Nåværende bud:
        {{bids[0].Amount}}
        <li><a href="auction/{{auction.Id}}">Se auksjon</a></li>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Datastructure:

```
interface Car {
  Id: number;
  CarType: string;
  flag: string;
  LicensePlate: string;
  KilometersDriven: number;
  Equipment: Array<Equipment>;
  FuelTypeId: number;
  Seats: number;
  GearTypeId: number;
  CityId: number;
  ColourId: number;
  Gears: number;
}

interface Auction {
  Id: number;
  Active: boolean;
  StartDate: Date;
  EndDate: Date;
  CarId: number;
}

interface Bid {
  AuctionId: number;
  Amount: number;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `{{allCars[auction.CarId].CarType}}` and `{{bids[auction.BidId].Amount}}`?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.

Comment: Can you post the data structure of `allCars` and `bids`? It is hard to troubleshoot without the component code.

Comment: Edited the question with the datastructure as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just implement two functions in your component that retrieve an object / an object property by its ID from the array.

Component:

```
public getCarType(carId: number): string {
  return this.allCars.find(car => car.Id === carId).CarType;
}

public getBid(auctionId: number): number {
  return this.bids.find(bid => bid.AuctionId === auctionId).Amount;
}
```

And then use the functions in your template:

```
Bil type: {{getCarType(auction.CarId)}}

Nåværende bud: {{getBid(auction.Id)}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much